# android Failed to start emulator:Cannot run program

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I have installed android SDK and android eclipse plugin successfully on Ubuntu.

Every thing was working fine until I removed Ubuntu and installed Linux Mint. 
I installed the SDK again and used the same eclipse copy I was using on Ubuntu but now all the android applications contain errors and I can not start the emulator.

When starting the emulator this message appears

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'test' Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/anas/android//tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory
```

While the android SDK is installed in the specified path and the file (emulator) is exists in the same path.

Also all my applications contains the same error `R can not be resolved to a variable`

What is the problem here?

Comment: The error about `R` sounds like a missing `import` statement. Even if the `import` statement is correct, if the aapt tool cannot run (which seems likely if you can't run the emulator), then R.java won't be generated and there will be no `R` class.

Comment: `/home/anas/android//tools/emulator` strange of having two backslashes give proper path `/home/anas/android/tools/emulator`

Comment: I have noticed the double backslashes but I do not know from where the second backslash comes from.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Installed on Ubuntu successfully.
   but not running avd

   If you're running a 64-bit system, you need to install ia32-libs

> ```
>   sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
> ```

1. R can not be resolved to a variable

This can be due to following Reason

- class is not the part of that package add proper package
- not properly defined in manifest file class path define it properly

clear and run the avd it will work

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04. running a 64 bit system this is exactly described in this article: http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/245-ubuntu-precise-install-android-sdk
Great answer @UsmanKurd

Comment: On current Ubuntu is replaced by packages: `lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`

Answer (score 10):

If cmd from fist comment doesn't work like in my case (64bit Crunchbang) then you may also try with :

> sudo aptitude install ia32-libs lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6

Answer (score 7):

I solved it doing a backup of the "emulator" and creating a symbolic link to the correct emulator:

```
mv emulator emulator_bup
ln -s emulator64-arm emulator
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the command-line tool android (`android avd`), and used Tools->Manage SDK to install 64 bit emulators.  I then mv'ed emulator to emulator.old, and emulator64-arm to emulator.  Now the AVD starts up.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need install packages any more!

In directory tools, there are many types of `emulator`, while my computer works with `emulator64-arm`! My system is `Linux Mint 16 amd64`! Good luck!

```
./emulator64-arm @yxphone -sdcard yxsd -scale 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you have written the specified path and the files are exists in the same path, but i suggest to check that one more time.

and like you are getting R cannot be resolved to a variable, do not worry:

**Reasons:**

1. Check *Package name in Manifest* File
2. If you are already getting something like this: *import com.version.bajrang.january.R;*
   so first of all *try to change package name* here, or secondly just *delete this line* and 
   clean your program
3. If you are *not getting* something like: *import com.version.bajrang.january.R*;
   then **add import packagename.R;**

I believe that you will get your answer.....

Comment: I have checked it again and I am sure the files are exists but I found another problem. When I tried to execute the `emulator` from the terminal it gives me the same error `No such file or directory`. This is weird

Comment: R can not be resolved to a variable  solved or not first of all and second show me the locations where have you installed or where you are saving for projects...then i will be able to tell you the reason..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your SDK path in eclipse has a mistake:

> Cannot run program "/home/anas/android//tools/emulator"

That double "//" may be the problem.  Check in Eclipse:  Window -> Preferences -> Android. There should be a field there pointing the SDK Location. Edit it.

Check your path : /home/anas/android/ to see if it really is where you put your SDK . If not repeat [these](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) steps to have it

The missing R resource message is a compile error right? Then in this case your emulator should not be the problem. However, if your SDK path is incorrect like I suspect, then .. you can expect this compile error along with any other android libraries import

Comment: This is the configured android path in eclipse `/home/anas/android` and I have checked that existence of the files in the same directory by navigating `cd /home/anas/android/tools` and I can see the files but when I tried to execute the emulator file from the terminal, it gives me the save error `No such file or directory`

Comment: @AnasRabei , so if you execute ~/anas/android/tools/emulator from terminal you get a "No such file or directory error" ?. If the file 'emulator' really is there, you should at least see "Emulator: ERROR:  no such file or directory". But you should get the no avd error message first

Comment: Post the whole error and output message you get from terminal

Answer (score -2):

This is sorted by running this on Ubuntu.

```
sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
```

Refer this: [Can't connect to emulator through ADB genymotion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144617/cant-connect-to-emulator-through-adb-genymotion)