# Issue setting up Android SDK - Failed to Start Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator

I'm new to Android Development and I am attempting, and apparently failing, to set up the Android SDK with Eclipse.  I thought I had everything working, but when I go to start the emulator I had set up I get the error message:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'MyDevice'
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/danny/android-sdk-linux//tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Note: I tried chmod-ing the directory containing the SDK as a search told me that would help, but it didn't work.

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm using Eclipse.  I also had another problem with the creation of a new project, but I'll wait and ask that in a new post in case the solution to this problem doesn't also solve that.

Comment: Your path may be invalid. You have a double // in android-sdk-linux//tools. Shouldn't it be only one /?

Comment: I noticed that as well, but I wasn't sure how I would fix it, or even if that was the problem.

Comment: This post may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578557/android-failed-to-start-emulatorcannot-run-program

Answer (score 0):

its your path as you have //in it..

directions on how to modify profile is at here:

[install on Ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Android-on-Ubuntu-Linux-with-Eclipse-IDE)